# Why does my NextAuthJS discord login work in the test environment but cannot be built to production? (NextJS 13)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to deploy a NextJS application to vercel. This is a test sign in model using AuthJS. When I run the program using `npm run dev`it works fine and I am able to log in to my discord account which is connected to an application on the developer portal. However, when I deploy it to Vercel and try and build the application for production I receive this error.

```
Type error: Route "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.
  "authOptions" is not a valid Route export field.
```

For context I am using NextJS 13 and it's app folder method of rendering pages along with the NextAuth.js.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    })
  ]
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

This is my code found inside the route, and the relative path to this folder is `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` which doesn't seem to have any problems when I run the program, only when trying to build it. I am not sure what to do as I am new to web development and have not encountered such an issue before and am perplexed. Any help is vastly appreciated.

Comment: You can try creating the authOptions object in a separate file, for example in "lib/auth.ts"
and then import it inside "app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issues - all I needed to do was remove the `export` from `export const authOptions`